# Adding a Continue button on a simple riddle game

Tags: android, android-activity, android-button

First time posting here! I'm a beginner in learning java and everything Android-related.

So, I'm stuck on a probably simple thing (I believe the answer is pretty simple too):
I'm creating a riddle game, where on each question/activity you're asked about something and when you give the right answer, the game lets you proceed to the next question. So far so good.

My problem is that I cannot comprehend how a "Continue" button (placed on the Main Menu) works, and what could be the code behind it. I mean, how will the game remember how far you've reached, and then give you the option to continue from there. I can only make the button take you to a specific level.

I hope there's no need for me to paste my code - if needed please tell me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello there welcome to StackOverFlow ! Sorry but yeah you have to show us your code in order for us to help you. Sorry it's that is how things work here

Comment: Also, narrow down your question to fit the Q&A format. You can Google or search on StackOverflow for researching about the problem and make your question very specific for us to answer. Also don't forget to see that you don't post a duplicate. :)

Comment: Ah, I'm a typical newcomer it seems :) I'll keep everything in mind! Though I've been searching quite a bit for an answer, I understand that my question wasn't as specific as it should have been - sorry about that. As it seems I have to study a bit more on SharedPreferences and then post my code... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Study Android `SharedPreferences`, it can be used to store simple data which can be used to keep track on the level.

[Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

Comment: Thank you a lot - seems like there's way more to learn about!